# logoff sessions except console

Tags: batch, logoff-scripts

There is an application in a multi-user environment that can only be open in one session on a workstation. The users move around frequently from PC to PC, leaving the application open, and the workstation locked. Disabling user switching is determinant to productivity. I need the system to force logoff any user besides the Consul session. The session ID is a variable that cannot be predicted. This is what I got so far...

```
@ echo off

query session > c:\users\session.txt

powershell -Command "Get-Content c:\users\session.txt | Where-Object {$_ -notmatch 'console'} | Set-Content c:\users\session2.txt"

for /f "skip=2 tokens=2," %i in (c:\users\session2.txt) DO C:\Windows\System32\logoff.exe %i
```

The goal is to put this into a .bat to run at user logon so whoever is ACTUALLY using the computer can use the applicaton. Dataloss of the inactive session is no concern. Ideally, rdp-tcp and services would stay active sessions as well.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this isn't quite what you're asking for but it's close: a means to have users logged off automatically when they're classed as idle:

https://4sysops.com/archives/automatically-log-off-idle-users-in-windows/

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. While the link you provided may answer the question, your answer will become useless if the linked page ever goes away. Please also include at least a summary of the solution here.

Comment: Good point, however as the solution is rather involved and depends on a the download of a little (free) utility, probably it's best just to provide a secondary link to much the same stuff:

http://www.intelliadmin.com/index.php/2011/11/automatically-logoff-inactive-users/

Answer (score 0):

Easier approach would be to simply kill all instances of the application that are NOT running in the active session.

Looks like you've got a good start on getting session information from PowerShell ... you can also use the *qwinsta* command to get all Session IDs.  From there, parse the list to only get the session IDs tagged "active"

From there, you can use the *taskkill* command with a filter excluding the active Session ID, but killing the process every where else:

taskkill /f /fi "SESSION ne 1" /im apptokill.exe

where 1 above was the Session ID of the active session.  The command above will terminate all instances of apptokill.exe NOT running in Session ID 1.

Comment: Two thoughts: With _query_ _session_ the Session ID is an unknown variable. With _taskkill_ user switching involves either unlocking the desktop or logging on. I do not want to kill the task if the user who has locked the desktop with the app running is unlocking - meaning that the last person logged on, when unlocking the screen, should have no change to processes or sessions.

Comment: The _query_ _session_ generates the print out of sessions, followed by the _get-content_ command in PS removes the line containing the console, and the id of that session along with it. This takes the guess work out of the IDs  _for_ ... _logoff_.

I think the problem is in my _for_ command syntax, unless my logic is flawed more in whole.

Comment: That works! Thanks!!! @jimmiller Jim, how does the "SESSION ne 1" argument work? For the test when I had my test user log in after me qwinstat gave them an ID of 2. I switched back to my session qwinstat labed as 1 and ran your syntax to kill there eaglesoft.exe.

Comment: I just tried this on the domain in question. The users are local admins. I switched users and could see the program to kill running in task manager with the inactive users name next to it. then in the command prompt I put taskkill /f /fi "SESSION ne 1" /im eaglesoft.exe